# everywhere special files name, run CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

My Windows 2008R2 VPS was hacked and I found out in system32 folder the sethc.exe was a copy of cmd.exe 
I replaced the sethc.exe with another exe file ,but nothing changed and the CMD appears by clicking on new sethc.exe file.
I realized everywhere every file that named sethc.exe, run CMD.exe
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Reinstall it. It's the only sane thing to do when a machine has been hacked. You can't be sure what other programs, services, etc have been modified.

Comment: Thanks, this is right.
But I want to know how they did it ?

Comment: There are lots of attack vectors if your server was not fully patched, and yet more if logged in users wernt careful. There is no way you will find out "how they did it". Just reinstall and move on

Comment: Don't know why this is put on hold. Question was clear: how can i fix it (sethc.exe always running cmd.exe) which i answered in a few paragraphs. The fact there should be a re-install done is besides the fact to fix the sethc.exe. There aren't a lot of other answers possible so why the hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to get a cmd prompt with <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> at the login prompt. (which is normally used for the accessibility options)

They did it like this:
(You can read about it [here](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/windows/sethcsystemlevelprompt/))

> Windows has a key in the registry called Image File Execution Options. This key does... stuff. One of the many things it does is allows for a per executable specific debugger. The thing is, it doesn't actually check if the executable is actually a debugger, it just launches it instead. Malware use this key as one of the ways to launch themselves. We're going to use it for a different purpose.
>
> Create a key under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options. Name it sethc.exe. Under sethc.exe make a new REG_SZ (string) value, name it Debugger. Edit the value to be "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"

So you'll find an entry for `sethc.exe` (while this should not be there). Now you know how to get rid of it but i agree with Teun and Mattias, you should re-install this machine because they could have left lots of other "goodies".